# How to play youtube videos in the Background using Presentation Class (Intel WiDi)

Tags: android, wifi, intel, android-wifi, wifi-direct

Am working with Wireless Displays. What i am trying to do is play an YouTube video on my secondary display and use my mobile screen for other purposes. I currently use Service/Presentation to stream data to the secondary screen while i do other activities on my mobile screen. I want to do the same with youtube videos. I am using YouTube API. Kindly help.

Comment: Hi.. I have also the same requirement. Can u plz help/guide in above.